# How to make animated GIFs work from Android WebView

Tags: android, android-widget, animated-gif

Animated GIF images rendered by Android's WebView do not seem to animate.  Has anyone figured out how to make them work? I'm testing on an N1 with 2.1-u1. None of the web settings available seem applicable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not supported YET. 
Read more about this here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

> For large memory phones like Droid and Nexus One, the two-line change has been made in Froyo (unreleased) 
>   to enable animated GIFs. For small memory phones, the change is not trivial and did not make it into this future 
>   release.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, if you are using a custom WebView, you can do these 2 things together:

- Enable Javascript for the Webview (Eg: https://github.com/LatinSuD/slidetypekeyboard/blob/master/src/com/latinsud/android/slidetypekeyboard/HelpActivity.java)
  Like: myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
- Then use javascript to swap images (Eg: https://github.com/LatinSuD/slidetypekeyboard/blob/master/assets/index.html)

Please note that this is not a solution for displaying GIFs, you must modify the content of the web, and convert/split GIF animations into different files (one for each frame) in any format (JPG, PNG, etc).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, animated GIFs are not supported on Android except as movie clips played by `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 2):

Animated GIFs are supported in Froyo (Android 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Use WebP format for Android.

https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

There are several online utilities available, to convert animated GIFs to WebP format (http://www.zamzar.com/convert/gif-to-webp/ is one example).

Note that WebP is not supported on most of the other browsers so you may need to apply some logic to select GIF or WebP based on platform.