# Why Webview freezes the Emulator with Gif immage?

Tags: android, webview

I am using HTML content (which is a gif image) to be viewed in a Webview. WEbview is successfully loaded the HTML content and the Gif image appeard. But, after some time the Emulator freezed and it stopped responses. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class ABC extends AppCompatActivity {
      WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview) ;
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hayder.html");

            }
  }
```

Comment: read this. android webview does not support gif. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2706123/4993283

Comment: Thanks for the help .. Webview doesn't support gif as the links explained .. But, I have seen some tutorials are doing it ..

Answer (score 0):

android manifest add this

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    ...
    >
```

Comment: Thank you .. I have tried your solution but the problem still the same ..